# Book about 2 spaceships one of which was trying to contain a zombie outbreak

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, space

Written in the form of logs.

One of the ships seems evil at first but as the story goes on it's revealed that it was trying to contain a zombie outbreak but the story was narrated from the POV of someone on the other ships. One of the ships is called Copernicus. It ends with the infected ship being nuked. Main characters are one male and one female. The ship is controlled by an AI.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any of the other character, ship or place names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Illuminae](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23395680-illuminae)* by Amie Kaufman & Jay Kristoff.

> The year is 2575, and two rival mega-corporations are at war over a planet that’s little more than a speck at the edge of the universe. Now with enemy fire raining down on them, Kady and Ezra — who are barely even talking to each other—are forced to evacuate with a hostile warship in hot pursuit.
>
> But their problems are just getting started. A plague has broken out and is mutating with terrifying results; the fleet’s AI may actually be their enemy; and nobody in charge will say what’s really going on. As Kady hacks into a web of data to find the truth, it’s clear the only person who can
> help her is the ex-boyfriend she swore she’d never speak to again.
>
> Told through a fascinating dossier of hacked documents — including emails, maps, files, IMs, medical reports, interviews, and more
>
> [image]

Notably, the three ships mentioned in the book are the Alexander, the Hypatia and the Copernicus.

Comment: Yes that's the one, thanks!